# CNAME (pointing to the same server) asks for credentials

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, cname-record

Let's say I have two Windows Servers:

- dc1
- dc2

And I have a CNAME record:

- MyFileServer (pointing to dc2)

If I from dc1 opens share `\\MyFileServer\c$`, then it works fine.

If I from dc2 opens share `\\MyFileServer\c$`, then it asks for credentials - and no matter what credentials I enter, it fails.

How can I fix it so I can open `\\MyFileServer\c$` from dc2?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

[Link to Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/accessing-server-locally-with-fqdn-cname-alias-denied)

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0
3. Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
4. In the Name column, type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.
5. Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify.
6. In the Value data box, type the CNAME or the DNS alias, that is used for the local shares on the computer, and then click OK.

> Note
>
> Type each host name on a separate line. If the BackConnectionHostNames
> registry entry exists as a REG_DWORD type, you have to delete the
> BackConnectionHostNames registry entry.

7. Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.